# How to check if a pseudo element exists or not through selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I need to know whether we can find the existence of a pseudo element like ::after and ::before

My aim is just to return true or false if it is present.

However it cannot be done using:

```
browser.driver.findElements(by.id('id')).size != 0
```

or

```
return !driver.findElements(by).isEmpty();
```

becasue they are psuedo elements and cannot be located through any CS or XPATH locators

Here is my HTML having ::after

```html
<div class="parent-class">
        <span class="child-class">Archive
        ::after
        </span>
        ::after
      </div>
```

Here is my HTML without having ::after

```html
<div class="parent-class">
        <span class="child-class">Archive
         ::after
        </span>
      </div>
```

Note: I need to verify only the ::after in DIV tag but not in SPAN tag

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the pseudo-elements cannot be located by paths or CSS locators. 
However, as an alternative, you can extract the inner HTML of the parent element and validate if it contains the "::after" text.

There are two ways of doing this. For the above scenario,

```
WebElement element = browser.driver.findElement(By.className('parent-class'))
String innerHTMLText = element.getAttribute('innerHTML');
if (innerHTMLText.contains("::after")){
   // Bingo !!
}
```

Or else

```
WebElement element = browser.driver.findElement(By.className('parent-class'))
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String innerHTMLText = js.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
if (innerHTMLText.contains("::after")){
   // Bingo !!
}
```

### EDIT 1

If you need to verify if only the div tag is having the pseudo-element you can get the span tag's HTML, get parent tag's HTML, remove span tag inner HTML from parent tag's HTML. Verify.

```
String divHTMLText = browser.driver.findElement(By.className('parent-class')).getAttribute('innerHTML');
String spanHTMLText = browser.driver.findElement(By.className('child-class')).getAttribute('innerHTML');
// replace all the whitespaces first for good measure
divHTMLText = divHTMLText.replaceAll("\\s+","")
spanHTMLText = spanHTMLText.replaceAll("\\s+","")
// replace the child html from parent's html with empty. which leaves us with the parent html code.
String divOnlyHTML = divHTMLText.replace(spanHTMLText, "");

if (divOnlyHTML.contains("::after")){
   // Bingo !!
}
```

Comment: What if the HTML looks like this

<div class="parent-class">
        <span class="child-class">"Archive"
        ::after
        </span>
        ::after
      </div>

Now, I need to check ::after only for div but not span

Comment: are you sure that String divHTMLText = browser.driver.findElement(By.className('parent-class')).getAttribute('innerHTML');  gets the whole inner HTMl along ::after. I guess no because, when I tried to print it on console it printed without the pseudo elements. There is no ::after in the console when I printed

Comment: I provided 2 methods to get the HTML code. did you try the 2nd option? Using JavascriptExecutor?

Comment: This doesn't work! `element.getAttribute('innerHTML')` returned string doesn't contain before or after. `js.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);` returns Object, not a String!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript, but try with this one:

```
WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(By.className("parent-class"));
boolean hasAfterPseudoElement = (boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
                "return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], '::after').content !== 'none';", parentElement);
```