# How to check if web element contains pseudo element. Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, pseudo-element

In my Java Selenium automation project I have to know about some web elements if they are containing pseudo elements or not.
I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497951/how-to-check-if-a-pseudo-element-exists-or-not-through-selenium) question and the answer there simply doesn't work.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772457/webdriver-select-element-that-has-before) looks better, however in my situation I already have a web element and I need to get it's content while in that answer the JavaScript receives a locator.
I absolutely do not familiar with JavaScript that's why I'm asking:
So, given a Selenium WebElement element. How can I know does this element contain pseudo element or not?
On a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Nkm.png) there is an element with red dot - the `::after` pseudo element while other elements doesn't have such red dot.
This is what I got from the dev tools as outerHTML for element containing the `after` pseudo element. i even can't see it there and it is just similar to other elements there who doesn't contain pseudo elements.

```
<div workspaceid="49426bdc-59fe-44ec-82ea-8f567407c04f" data-test-id="9B1qjz0kWcfO" class="list-item ListItem__ListItemComponent-bsdtqz-0 dgogUS RoleItem-sc-1n184cw-0 jyfJwu role-item"><p class="text-component Texts__GenericText-sc-1dju4ks-0 czkGYX name p">9B1qjz0kWcfO </p></div>
```

Comment: Is it sufficient to check only for the pseudoelements `::before` and `::after`? Or do you need it to work for any text in a pseudo element?

Comment: Also could you please paste some sample HTML, maybe like what's in your screenshot, and/or the outerHTML of an element containing a pseudo element for me to test against?

Comment: All what I want is to check if some specific element contains `::after` in it or not.

Comment: Why can't you just grab the outerHTML and check whether it contains `::after`? Why do you need JavaScript at all?

Comment: See the outerHTML I pasted here. it doesn't contain any pseudo elements. Or it's just me who can't see them or doesn't know how to get them? I indeed do not know JS at all...

Comment: Oh that is interesting... I will think and experiment on this it's an interesting problem

Comment: The same is with innerHTML, it doesn't contain those pseudo elements

Comment: What is the use case here ? Why do you wanna grab `::after`

Comment: The left column contains "roles". In case some specific role is incomplete it presents a red dot indicator. In my tests I want to randomly select some role but sometimes this must be a complete role. I can get a random element from a list so it will return a random web element. Now I need to check if that web element contains `after` pseudo element - in this case I will try getting another random element from the list until I get one without `::after` (always there are complete roles there) or continue flow if the element doesn't contain the `::after` pseudo element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `WebElement` as an argument instead of locator in the [JavascriptExecutor](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html). Using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) you can get all css properties for the `pseudo-element`. Check CSS in devtools, find the red dot css property and then you can check it.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

// JavaScript to get any css property include pseudo-element. 
// Arguments is an array of parameters passed to the executeScript method (standart Selenium functionality)
String js = "return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], arguments[1]).getPropertyValue(arguments[2]);";

// Use WebElement instead of locator. 
// Property "content" is an example of property, you should check css and get the red dot
String cssProperty = (String) jsExecutor.executeScript(js, element, ":after", "content");

// Check for the red dot css property
```